# Get date in seconds in Python with lambda

Tags: python, django

I use the following code to get the time in seconds

```
NowS = lambda : round(datetime.now().timestamp())

class api_REMITTANCE_(APIView):

    Now_ = NowS()
    def post(self,request):
      return_serial = {"status_" : "OK_","time":self.Now_}`
```

But surprisingly, when I call again a minute later, it returns the previous time

Comment: Why "surprisingly"? You called `NowS()` *once* and saved the result as a class attribute. If you want the current time, do e.g. `{"status_" : "OK_", "time": NowS()}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're calling the function `Now_ = NowS()` only once

you should keep it inside your function to be called every time the end user makes a post request like this:

```
class api_REMITTANCE_(APIView):
  
    def post(self,request):
      Now_ = NowS()
      return_serial = {"status_" : "OK_","time":Now_}`
```

Comment: you're right I'll edit it

Comment: Please fix your example code: `self.Now_` will raise an attribute-error.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `Now_ = NowS()` is executed once when the class is defined, not when instantiated, so all instances receive the very same value.

Change the function body to::

```
return_serial = {"status_" : "OK_","time": NowS()}`
```

and it should gets evaluated for every call

Comment: @swifty yes sorry